# What is the Paging memory proxy equivalent technique in Ext JS 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

In version 3.x of Ext JS, I have a store with a json proxy to fetch the complete data set from the server, then I use that store as a reader in a store with a PagingMemoryProxy with the original store as the reader to provide paged data for a grid panel.

The json store :-

```
var fleetReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
      root:'results',
      successProperty:'success',
      totalProperty:'total',
      idProperty:'vid'
    },
    fleetRec
);

var fleetDs = new Ext.data.Store({
  proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
    url: 'request/getfleet',
    timeout: 10000
  }),
  reader:fleetReader
});
```

Then I create the paged version of this store as follows :-

```
fleetPagedDs = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy: new Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy(fleetDs.reader.jsonData),
    reader: fleetDs.reader,
    remoteSort: true
});
```

Would someone be able to tell me how to the equivalent of this in ExtJS 4?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Were you able to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for [Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy)?

From the Sencha docs:

> Paging Memory Proxy, allows to use paging grid with in memory dataset.

Comment: Not exactly, I am wanting to piggy back a PagingMemoryProxy based store on the back on a Json based proxy store so that I don't need to re-read the data from the server each time.

Comment: You don't need a second store. Just make your data request using `Ext.Ajax.request` and then load your store manually using `store.loadData`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It could just be me, but calling store.loadData with the data from the Ext.Ajax.request populates the store with the entire data set, rather than honouring the start/limit properties and doesn't trigger the load event on the store. The latter is not so much an issue as the former.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you essentially want to make your paged requests to the server, but cache each page in your PagingMemoryProxy instead of calling back each time?

Comment: Nope, I want to make one request to the server for the complete set of data and essentially have that in memory on the client side. Then make paged requests of that in-memory client side dataset. This is what was achieved in the code above with the previous version of extjs and it worked really well.

Comment: @csl-dev have you found the solution for in memory pagination?